# How do I combine multiple excel sheets into one - taking visible cells only (no formulas)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the below code but this takes all cells, including formula cells.

I tried to include `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` , but wherever I seem to put it I cannot get it right.

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
' copy headings
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
' work through sheets
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
    Sheets(J).Activate ' make the sheet active
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select ' select all cells in this sheets
    ' select all lines except title
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    ' copy cells selected in the new sheet on last line
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning chaps,

A few days after you asked this questions I was having similar issues with a Macro similar to this [Jerry Sullivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3808628/jerry-sullivan)

Gave me a hand try this it might work for you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineData()
'--combines data from all sheets
'  assumes all sheets have exact same header fields as the
'    first sheet; however the fields may be different order.
'--combines using copy-paste. could be modified to pasteValues only

 Dim lNdxSheet As Long, lNextRow As Long, lDestCol As Long
 Dim lColCount As Long, lRowCount As Long
 Dim rHeaders As Range
 Dim sHeader As String
 Dim vMatch As Variant, vHeaders As Variant
 Dim wksCombined As Worksheet

 With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .DisplayAlerts = False
 End With

 '--add new sheet for results
 Set wksCombined = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1))

 '--optional: delete existing sheet "Combined"
 On Error Resume Next
 Sheets("Combined").Delete
 On Error GoTo 0

 With wksCombined
   .Name = "Combined"
   '--copy headers that will be used in destination sheet
   Set rHeaders = Sheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(1)
   rHeaders.Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")
 End With
 '--read headers into array
 vHeaders = rHeaders.Value
 lColCount = UBound(vHeaders, 2)
 lNextRow = 2

 For lNdxSheet = 2 To Sheets.Count
   '--count databody rows of continguous dataset at A1
   lRowCount = Sheets(lNdxSheet).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
   If lRowCount > 0 Then
      For lDestCol = 1 To lColCount
         sHeader = vHeaders(1, lDestCol)
         '--search entire first col in case field is rSourceData
         vMatch = Application.Match(sHeader, Sheets(lNdxSheet).Range("1:1"), 0)

         If IsError(vMatch) Then
            MsgBox "Header: """ & sHeader & """ not found on sheet: """ _
               & Sheets(lNdxSheet).Name
            GoTo ExitProc
         End If
         With Sheets(lNdxSheet)
         '--copy-paste this field under matching field in combined
           .Cells(2, CLng(vMatch)).Resize(lRowCount).Copy
           '  Option 1: paste values only
           wksCombined.Cells(lNextRow, lDestCol).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

           '  Option 2: paste all including formats and formulas
           '  wksCombined.Cells(lNextRow, lDestCol).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)  
        End With
      Next lDestCol
      lNextRow = lNextRow + lRowCount
   End If ' lRowCount > 0

 Next lNdxSheet
ExitProc:
 With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .DisplayAlerts = True
 End With

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but try this and see if it helps.